# Read CSV files and organising the data in Java

Tags: java, csv

I was wondering anyone one can help me please?

I am trying to write a java program that read from a csv file called matches.csv.
A single football match can end with a win or a draw: in first case the winner team get 3 points and the loser none, in the second case of draw each of the two teams get 1 point.

In the file it contains the following data.

```
17/08/2013 Arsenal Aston Villa 1 3
24/08/2013 Aston Villa Liverpool 0 1
```

This means that a match has been played on the 17/08/2013 where Arsenal scored 1 goal while Aston Villa 3 goals: thus Arsenal got 0 points while Aston Villa 3 points.

How can I structure my output to make it make it read

```
Position Team Played Points
1 Aston Villa 2 3
2 Liverpool 1 3
3 Arsenal 1 0
```

Here is my current attempt.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teams
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "matches.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try
        {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext())
            {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        }  
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: You should reorganize your data; how will you codify a match between Aston Villa and Milton Keynes?

Comment: how do i reorganize the data using java?

Comment: @fge I'm assuming the data is tab-delimited rather than space-delimited...I hope.

Comment: Can anyone help me please?
The CSV file contains
17/08/2013 Arsenal Aston Villa 1 3
24/08/2013 Aston Villa Liverpool 0 1

In java eclipse how do I use read the file and arrange it so the output will be look this:

Position Team         Played  Points
1        Aston Villa  2       3
2        Liverpool    1       3
3        Arsenal      1       0

Answer (score 1):

First, your input has to be a parseable CSV. So, use commas.

Supposing the file had commas, it would be something like

```
dateddmmyyyy,team1name,team2name,team1score,team2score
17/08/2013,Arsenal,Aston Villa,1,3
24/08/2013,Aston Villa,Liverpool,0,1
```

Then you can use the file you pasted here. Instead of your System.out.println, use something like

```
parseLine(data);
```

ParseLine would read the line and break it into pieces. I suggest you use the split(",") function to get the pieces you want, then just reference them by index.